# Porque uma query com variável localStorage não funciona?

Tags: php, javascript, localstorage

Estou fazendo um sistema em PHP onde o usuário deve escolher alguns parâmetros e então obter resultados o mais restritos possível.

Para isso eu armazeno a primeira variável usando o `LocalStorage` em JavaScript e tudo funciona perfeitamente bem, porém, somente quando eu literalmente escrevo a variável à mão.Mas ambas as query são idênticas.

Qual pode ser o problema?

```
SELECT * FROM tb_operadora WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '1', id_produto ) AND FIND_IN_SET('1', id_regioes )
```

A variável em questão é a segunda, de `id_regioes`. Quando ela é montada automáticamente, não *printa* nada, mas se escrevo a variavel na mão, ela funciona.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/local.php'); ?>
<?php
if (isset ($_GET['A'])) {
$A = $_GET['A'];
mysql_select_db($database_local, $local);
$query_porRegiao = "SELECT * FROM tb_operadora WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '" . $A . "', id_regioes )" ;
$porRegiao = mysql_query($query_porRegiao, $local) or die(mysql_error());
$row_porRegiao = mysql_fetch_assoc($porRegiao);
$totalRows_porRegiao = mysql_num_rows($porRegiao);

echo $query_porRegiao;
?>
<?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_porRegiao['id_operadora']?>"><?php echo $row_porRegiao['nome_operadora']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_porRegiao = mysql_fetch_assoc($porRegiao));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($porRegiao);
  if($rows > 0) {
mysql_data_seek($porRegiao, 0);
$row_porRegiao = mysql_fetch_assoc($porRegiao);
mysql_free_result($porRegiao);
} 
}
//showProduto
if (isset ($_GET['B'])) {
$B = $_GET['B'];
?>
<script>var regioes = window.localStorage.getItem('regiao');</script>
<?php $A = "<script>document.write(regioes)</script>";
//echo $A;
mysql_select_db($database_local, $local);
$query_Produto = "SELECT * FROM tb_operadora WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '" . $B . "', id_produto ) AND FIND_IN_SET('" . $A . "', id_regioes )";
$Produto = mysql_query($query_Produto, $local) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Produto = mysql_fetch_assoc($Produto);
$totalRows_Produto = mysql_num_rows($Produto);

echo $query_Produto;
?>
<?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_Produto['id_operadora']?>"><?php echo $row_Produto['nome_operadora']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_Produto = mysql_fetch_assoc($Produto));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($Produto);
if($rows > 0) {
mysql_data_seek($Produto, 0);
$row_Produto = mysql_fetch_assoc($Produto);
mysql_free_result($Produto);
}  

}
?>
```

Comment: Não entendi onde está a variável. O exemplo que você deu é o que foi escrito na mão? Se for, poste um exemplo onde você tenta concatenar a variável. Também não entendi bem onde entra o JS e onde entra o PHP na pergunta.

Comment: podes dar um exemplo de código que define essas variáveis? e como fica o código quando "escreves a variável na mão"? não estarás a misturar conceitos _server_ vs _client_ side?

Comment: Não sei se posso fazer isso, mas vou editar a pergunta e adicionar o código.

Comment: Obrigado por editar Sergio, não sei como deixar assim bem formatado e espero não estar quebrando regras do site com isso

Comment: @MarcelloPatto não tens que agradecer, estamos aqui para ajudar. Acho que estás a misturar conceitos. Quando fazes `<?php $A = "<script>document.write(regioes)</script>";` isso não vai dar nenhum outro valor na variável `$A` do que essa string como está. Tens de usar ajax ou url para passar essa info para uma variável PHP. O que está no `$_GET['A'];`? como é a aplicação no lado do cliente?

Comment: O valor é passado sim Sergio, pois eu o vejo na Query quando mando
`echo $query_Produto`, Então imagino que se o php consegue *printar* a query exatamente igual a que escrevo, ela deveria funionar, não?

Comment: @Sergio Perdão, a edição ocorreu quase que simultânea. Erro meu.

Comment: Como ainda estou programando, não vejo problema em passar a url: [link]http://www.we-broker.com.br/simulador/beta/getOper.php?B=1[/link]
login: convidado
senha: ppp123

Comment: Se você inspecionar a página que mandei, vai ver que em localStorage há armazenado o valor regia = 1

Comment: @Sergio, conseguiu acessar?

Comment: @MarcelloPatto nõ pede nenhum login, mas tenho outras duvidas que deves juntar á pergunta. Sabes o que é AJAX? não seria caso de usar isso? apontando para [este link](http://www.we-broker.com.br/simulador/beta/getOper.php?B=2&A=3) ?

Comment: Sim, sei o que é AJAX, mas ainda sou iniciante nesse assunto... quanto a não pedir login, acho que ainda não fechei a página.
Essa página já é o resultado de um apontamento feito pelo AJAX da página requisitante.
[link]http://www.we-broker.com.br/simulador/beta/simulador[/link] <- essa vai pedir login e senha